# Avoid the physical back button in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to avoid that the android users play my game and get gameover, that they simply click the back button and come back to the game.

This is my code from jumping of my GameActivity to jump into the new GameOver Activity. What a command could I use? I simply want to come back to the main activity not the gameActivity.

```
private void checkFails(){
    TextView failsleft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fails);
    if(fails < 1){
        failsleft.setText("Fails left: "+fails);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOverActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }else{
        failsleft.setText("Fails left: "+fails);
        fails--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your GameActivity is started by MainActivity, you can use an extra to tell the main activity that the game is ended. So you need to start the GameActivity with `startActivityWithResult`.

In **MainActivity**, start the **GameActivity** with `startActivityForResult()`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    // Request code for handling the GameActivity result
    // make it final so it can be changed.
    private static final int gameOverRequestCode = 777;

    // Start GameActivity
    private void startTheGame() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
      // start the GameActivity and wait for the result.
      startActivityForResult(intent, gameOverRequestCode);
    }


    @Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      switch (requestCode) {

        // Handle the result from GameActivity.
        // when the result is accepted from GameActivity, start the GameOverActivity.
        case gameOverRequestCode:
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOverActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }
          break;
      }
    }

    ...
}
```

In **GameActivity**, send the result when the game is over:

```
private void checkFails(){
    TextView failsleft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fails);
    if(fails < 1){
        failsleft.setText("Fails left: "+fails);

        // Send the result back to main activity
        Intent i = getIntent();
        // you can add any extra here, for example, game state.
        // i.putExtra("extra_key", value);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);

        // Finish the GameActivity because we don't need it anymore.
        finish();

    }else{
        failsleft.setText("Fails left: "+fails);
        fails--;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added exactly everything. In the mainActivity, there are two red errors: the first: the requestCode in the switch; Constant expression required;  the intent in the mainactivity: Intent(this, GameOverActivity.class);  Method call expected. and where do i have to write all this in my mainactivity?

Comment: Ohhh... I made an error. The requestCode variable is clashing with the requestCode in the switch. I'll update the code.

Comment: and why is it so good to use that long understandable code if i could take the first answer to override the back button?

Comment: Of course you can override `onBackPressed()` in your `GameOverActivity`. But after that, you still need to handle the GameActivity which still alive when you're showing the GameOverActivity.

Comment: ok i will try yours. just for finish the game after gameover wait i will implement this in a second.

Comment: if I'm not wrong, overriding `onBackPressed()` will make your activity level like this: `MainActivity -> GameActivity -> GameOverActivity`. So, all the control for GameOverActivity is handled by GameActivity. Using startActivityForResult will gives this: `MainActivity -> GameOverActivity`.

Comment: Where do I have to put the first 3 statements  before adding the override? i mean i need another method!

Comment: but i cant override in another method

Comment: Ohh... You need to move the other code beside the overrided code to another method where you're launching the GameActivity. I have updated code to make it clear.

Comment: i‘ve got the method openGame to start the game activity. can you show this to me? edit

Comment: `startTheGame` is the same purpose for your `openGame `.

Comment: it isnt working for me ... same errors constand expression required and method call expected in main

Comment: `gameOverRequestCode` should be class scope (outside the method). I've fixed it. Sorry, it seems that I need throughly describe the code.

Comment: I have added the description in the comment.

Comment: it works but what have i reached? that the game ends? but why do you use 777 ?

Comment: Congratulations! The purpose of using the above code is to avoid a coupled activity. When you're using `onBackPressed()`, you make your GameActivity and GameOverActivity tightly coupled. So, the GameOverActivity will be depends on GameActivity. Using the above code is to limit error propagation, this is to achieve a clean code. 

You can use any number, I just love the 777 number. 7  is the number of completeness and perfection.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method "OnBackPressed" in Activity and do any custom logic there. Here is a link to the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()